# udev rule to make certain ports always correspond to certain devices

Tags: linux, hard-drive, udev, rules

Basically my problem is that I am on a server which constantly switches around hdd's. What I want to achieve is have having devices tied to the physical ports on the hardware.

like `/dev/sda` is port 0 `/dev/sdb` is port 0 and so on.

I have been reading about udev rules and it always comes back to using serials and such. however since my hardware is constantly changing I can't use that. I need to assign ports to device files.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this for external hard drives. I got my info using `lsscsi`, which will print something like the following:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    <descriptor>    /dev/sda
[1:0:0:0]    disk    <descriptor>    /dev/sdb
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  <descriptor>    /dev/sr0
```

Where 0,1,2 correspond to the port IDs. Then something similar to the following rule should do what you want:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*1", KERNELS=="1:0:0:0", SYMLINK+="<label_1>"
```

(Note I haven't checked that this works for internal drives - my external ones needed 'usb' rather than 'block' as the subsystem type)